# Visualising node memory in grafana and prometheus with node exporter

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to use grafana dashboard ([ID 395](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/395-main-overview/)) show several docker container and host parameters. It was not showing node memory earlier This is how it is showing node memory:

[image]

Current queries are:

- H: `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes`
- G: `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes`

I have following doubts:

Q1: Why it does not show any line chart for "Unavailable Memory" i.e. query G?

Q2: Why the y axis shows max memory as 3.73 GiB and not 15.2 GiB?

Also note that when I hide (clicked that eye button) query H, it showed query G as graph follows:

[image]

This I feel is showing total memory itself.

Whats going wrong here?

**Update**

Here is a panel JSON if it helps:

```
{
  "datasource": {
    "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77",
    "type": "prometheus"
  },
  "aliasColors": {
    "Available Memory": "#7EB26D",
    "Unavailable Memory": "#BF1B00"
  },
  "dashLength": 10,
  "editable": true,
  "fill": 4,
  "grid": {},
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 4,
    "w": 4,
    "x": 14,
    "y": 0
  },
  "id": 20,
  "isNew": true,
  "legend": {
    "avg": false,
    "current": false,
    "max": false,
    "min": false,
    "show": false,
    "total": false,
    "values": false
  },
  "lines": true,
  "linewidth": 3,
  "links": [],
  "nullPointMode": "null as zero",
  "options": {
    "alertThreshold": true
  },
  "pluginVersion": "9.5.2",
  "pointradius": 5,
  "renderer": "flot",
  "seriesOverrides": [],
  "spaceLength": 10,
  "stack": true,
  "targets": [
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "container_memory_rss{name=~\".+\"}",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "D",
      "step": 30,
      "editorMode": "code",
      "range": true
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "sum(container_memory_rss{name=~\".+\"})",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "A",
      "step": 20
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "container_memory_usage_bytes{name=~\".+\"}",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{name}}",
      "refId": "B",
      "step": 20
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "container_memory_rss{id=\"/\"}",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "C",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "sum(container_memory_rss)",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "E",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_Buffers",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "node_memory_Dirty",
      "refId": "N",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_MemFree",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "F",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "editorMode": "code",
      "expr": "node_memory_MemTotal_bytes",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "Available Memory",
      "range": true,
      "refId": "H",
      "step": 4
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "editorMode": "code",
      "expr": "node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes",
      "hide": false,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "Unavailable Memory",
      "range": true,
      "refId": "G",
      "step": 4
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_Inactive",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "I",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_KernelStack",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "J",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_Active",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "K",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_MemTotal - (node_memory_Active + node_memory_MemFree + node_memory_Inactive)",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "Unknown",
      "refId": "L",
      "step": 40
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_MemFree + node_memory_Inactive ",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "M",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "container_memory_rss{name=~\".+\"}",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "{{__name__}}",
      "refId": "O",
      "step": 30
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "c486a608-7914-471a-9e80-81a5cec6ce77"
      },
      "expr": "node_memory_Inactive + node_memory_MemFree + node_memory_MemAvailable",
      "hide": true,
      "intervalFactor": 2,
      "legendFormat": "",
      "refId": "P",
      "step": 40
    }
  ],
  "thresholds": [],
  "timeRegions": [],
  "title": "Available Memory on Node",
  "tooltip": {
    "msResolution": true,
    "shared": true,
    "sort": 0,
    "value_type": "individual"
  },
  "type": "graph",
  "xaxis": {
    "mode": "time",
    "show": false,
    "values": [],
    "name": null,
    "buckets": null
  },
  "yaxes": [
    {
      "format": "bytes",
      "label": "",
      "logBase": 1,
      "max": 4200000000,
      "min": 0,
      "show": true
    },
    {
      "format": "short",
      "logBase": 1,
      "show": false
    }
  ],
  "yaxis": {
    "align": false
  },
  "bars": false,
  "dashes": false,
  "error": false,
  "fillGradient": 0,
  "hiddenSeries": false,
  "percentage": false,
  "points": false,
  "steppedLine": false,
  "timeFrom": null,
  "timeShift": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which panel type did you use and how did you configure it.
I guess it is `Time serie`, so in that case it looks like you have set 100% `Fill opacity`, so one "red" time series is just hidden behind "red" time series. You may have also misconfigured `Max\Soft max` options.

Comment: I have not delved deeper in Grafana. I just imported [dashboard with ID 395 from grafana.com](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/395-main-overview/). So the panel came pre-configured in that dashboard. I have added panel JSON at the bottom of original question if it helps. Please Let me know if I should share more information. Just to add, this was old Graph visualization. Grafana was giving option to migrate to newer time series visualization. I tried, but it is still renders the same.